# event listener wrapper function - event listeners bound more than once for elements

Tags: javascript, html

Below is a wrapper function for event listeners for an element, how do I handle event listeners that can be bound more than once for an element in my event listener wrapper function. And what does that mean if event listeners are bound more than once, I just heard the terminology in another post

```
var evts = (function () {
  'use strict';

  var listeners = [],
      add,
      remove;

  add = function (evt, elem, fn, capture) {
    var callback = function (evt) {      
      fn.call(elem, evt, evt && evt.target ? evt.target : window.event.srcElement);
    };

    listeners.push({
      evt: evt,
      elem: elem,
      fn: fn,
      callback: callback,
      capture, capture,
      removed: false
    });

    if (elem.addEventListener) {
      elem.addEventListener(evt, callback, capture);
    } else if (elem.attachEvent) {
      elem.attachEvent('on' + evt, callback, capture);
    } else {
      elem['on' + evt] = callback;
    }
  };

  remove = function (evt, elem, fn, capture) {

    var callback = function (evt) {      
      fn.call(elem, evt, evt && evt.target ? evt.target : window.event.srcElement);
    };

    callback();

    listeners.forEach(function (obj, i) {
      if (obj.evt === evt && obj.elem === elem && 
          !obj.removed) {
        obj.removed = true;
        callback = obj.callback;
        listeners.splice(i, 1);
      }
    });

    if (elem.removeEventListener) {
      elem.removeEventListener(evt, callback, capture);
    } else if (elem.detachEvent) {
      elem.detachEvent('on' + evt, callback, capture);
    } else {
      elem['on' + evt] = null;
    }
  };

  return {
    add: add,
    remove: remove
  };
}());
```

e.g removeEvent Listener

```
$(this).off('click', function(e) { console.log('goodbye') });
```

Comment: I used callback at the start because if I had an off function with a call back I execute that function then removeListener with obj.callback is that not good

Comment: @some I used that call back at the start because the function doesn't execute in elem.removeEventListener(event, callback, capture) how should I write it.

Comment: @some I thought that was how off functions work. I thought you would execute a function on the off callback. Correct me if I'm wrong, how should it look, have a look at my code upadrted example at the end

Comment: the callback executes at the start which is just fn function not the initial callback for the event then the callback for the initial event gets used so the listener is removed

Comment: @some have a look again, the off callback that gets parsed in is executed at the start which is just fn function then the call back is changed to the actual event listeners event so it can be removed

Comment: I'm learning vanilla javascript and I'm building my own javascript library I'm just using $ like jquery

Comment: @same Ok with the off function does the callback have to be the same as the on function

Comment: I can't help you if you don't answer my questions.

Answer (score 1):

It appears the OP code is a ES5 class with no prototypes? The following demo is a ES6 `class` called `Binder()` -- a modified version found in this [article](https://www.ericponto.com/blog/2014/10/05/es6-dom-library/):

- The `constructor` accepts a selector (string with CSS/jQuery syntax) and returns a NodeList nested within an object `{` **NodeList** `}`
- The first method `.each(callback)` will invoke a given callback (a function called when an event is triggered) on each node (element, tag, etc).
- Next method `.on(event, callback)` will use `.each()` method to bind a given event and register a given callback to each node.
- Last method `.off(event, callback)` removes an `eventListener()` with the given event and callback.

`Binder()` is instantiated with this syntax:

```
const $ = selector => new Binder(selector)
```

Here's how to bind the input event to all `<input>s` and calls `function validate()`:

```
$('input').on('input', validate)
```

```js
class Binder {
  constructor(selector) {
    const elements = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
    this.length = elements.length;
    Object.assign(this, elements);
  }
  each(callback) {
    for (let node of Array.from(this)) {
      callback.call(node);
    }
    return this;
  }
  on(event, callback) {
    return this.each(function() {
      this.addEventListener(event, callback);
    });
  }
  off(event, callback) {
    return this.each(function() {
      this.removeEventListener(event, callback);
    });
  }
};

const $ = selector => new Binder(selector);

const colorBtn = e => {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.matches('button')) {
    if (tgt.matches('.off')) {
      tgt.style.color = tgt.id;
    } else {
      tgt.style.color = '#000';
    }
    tgt.classList.toggle('off');
  }
  return false;
}

const unbindBtn = e => {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.checked) {
    $('button').off('click', colorBtn);
  } else {
    $('button').on('click', colorBtn);
  }
  return false;
}

$('button').on('click', colorBtn);
$('#unbind').on('change', unbindBtn);
```

```css
button {
  display: block;
  width: 8ch;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  cursor: pointer
}

button::before {
  content: attr(id);
}

.highlight {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<button id="red" class='off'></button>
<button id="green" class='off'></button>
<button id="blue" class='off'></button>
<label for='unbind'>Remove Event Listeners<input id='unbind' type='checkbox'>
```